# How to set a command button in access to transfer data from one table to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two tables in MS Access. I use one of them for my form data entry and another one for saving data. The second table is linked to SQL Server.

I want to set a command button in my form that when I click on it, the data transfers from the first table to the next one and all transferred data is deleted from my first table. I used this code but it does not working

```
Private Sub TransferData_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim ftrSQL As String

strSQL = "insert into dbo_gradingdw (pdate, item, color, grade, issue, description)" &
        "sellect pdate, item, color, grade, issue, description" & _
        "from tblgradingaccdw;"

ftrSQL = "delete from tblgradingaccdw" &
        "where (pdate)" & _
        "in (sellect pdate from dbo_gradingdw);"
      
      strSQL = "insert into dbo_gradingdw from tblgradingaccdw"
      
      ftrSQL = "delete from dbo_gradingdw where [pdate] in (sellect pdate from dbo_gradingdw"
         
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

CurrentDb.Execute ftrSQL

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76370610/edit) your question to include the full and complete error messages - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: I expect you'll be getting errors due to problems in your query strings such as `sellect`, `..., descriptionfrom ...` and lack of closing brackets `)`.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Make sure spaces included at end of breaking lines so don't run together when compiled. Your first SQL will construct like: `descriptionfrom` and the second will `tblgradingaccdwwhere`; neither of which can be executed. Missing a paren from last SQL - why would you need WHERE clause if deleting every record?